# JAXB exception while deploying spring-ws web service

Tags: java, exception, jaxb, spring-ws

I have an xsd which is used withing a soap web service implemented using spring-ws.
one of the types is defined as follows:

```
   <xsd:complexType name="DateTimeWithTimeZone">
      <xsd:annotation>
         <xsd:documentation>An extension to the standard dateTime, that forces the use of a proper time zone.</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:attribute name="DateTime" type="xsd:dateTime" use="required">
         <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>The date time value</xsd:documentation>
         </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:attribute>
      <xsd:attribute name="TimeZone" type="xsd:string" use="optional" default="UTC">
         <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>The time zone of the relevant date/time, should be a standard time zone from the Time Zone database at http://www.iana.org/time-zones</xsd:documentation>
         </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:attribute>
   </xsd:complexType>
```

My problem is that when my JBoss loads, I get this exception:

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'marshaller' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
@XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar com.example.schema.DateTimeWithTimeZone.dateTime
        at com.example.schema.DateTimeWithTimeZone
   ...
```

The generated java file is the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DateTimeWithTimeZone")
public class DateTimeWithTimeZone {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "DateTime", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar dateTime;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "TimeZone")
    protected String timeZone;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
    public void setDateTime(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
        this.dateTime = value;
    }
    public String getTimeZone() {
        if (timeZone == null) {
            return "UTC";
        } else {
            return timeZone;
        }
    }
    public void setTimeZone(String value) {
        this.timeZone = value;
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, that seems odd. I can't find a good reason why this doesn't work. Have you tried using a custom bindings file to convert xs:datetime to use a Java `Calendar` object? It seems to break on the `XmlGregorianCalendar` somehow. Perhaps a normal `Calendar` will work.

That file would look something like:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <globalBindings>
    <javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
      parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDate"
      printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDate"
    />
  </globalBindings>
</bindings>
```

You can add that to your pom.xml like this:

```
<configuration>
    <bindingFiles>/path/to/bindings.xjb</bindingFiles>
<configuration>
```

Or by using xjc like:

```
xjc schema.xsd -b bindings.xjb
```